# Use VirtualBox provider by default on Fedora 21

Tags: fedora, virtualbox, libvirt, vagrant

Right now, any time I use vagrant, it tries to use `libvirt` as the provider. I want to use VirtualBox by default.

`vagrant-libvirt` is not installed.

It's bothersome because some commands don't work, like `vagrant status`:

```
[florian@localhost local]$ vagrant status
The provider 'libvirt' could not be found, but was requested to
back the machine 'foobar'. Please use a provider that exists.
[florian@localhost local]$ vagrant status --provider=virtualbox
An invalid option was specified. The help for this command
is available below.

Usage: vagrant status [name]
    -h, --help                       Print this help
```

Comment: I would've loved to add the following tags, but do not have enough reputation to create them: [tag:fedora-21] [tag:libvirt]

Comment: I added `libvirtd` to the question. I don't think it's valuable to have a tag for every specific Fedora version, especially when they are EOL in as little as 12mos after release.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

According to [vagrant's documentation](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/providers/default.html), the default provider should be `virtualbox`, and the `VAGRANT_DEFAULT_PROVIDER` variable lets you override it.

However, `VAGRANT_DEFAULT_PROVIDER` is empty, so it should be `virtualbox`, right? Well, if I set the variable to `virtualbox`, it works again. So I guess fedora sets the default variable somewhere else.

Solution:

```
$ echo "export VAGRANT_DEFAULT_PROVIDER=virtualbox" >> ~/.bashrc
$ source ~/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 4):

This is just my experience on encountering this problem.

On executing `vagrant up`, i got this

```
The provider 'libvirt' could not be found, but was requested to
back the machine 'default'. Please use a provider that exists.
```

I tried the commands provided above

```
echo "export VAGRANT_DEFAULT_PROVIDER=virtualbox" >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

Then I executed `vagrant up`

```
The provider 'virtualbox' that was requested to back the machine
'default' is reporting that it isn't usable on this system. The
reason is shown below:

VirtualBox is complaining that the kernel module is not loaded. Please
run `VBoxManage --version` or open the VirtualBox GUI to see the error
message which should contain instructions on how to fix this error.
```

Using `VBoxManage --version`, it gave me

```
The vboxdrv kernel module is not loaded. Either there is no module
available for the current kernel (4.0.4-303.fc22.x86_64) or it failed to
load. Please recompile the kernel module and install it
```

and prompted me to execute `sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup` which solved my problem.

Comment: Just virtualbox that wasn't correctly setup then, not directly related to vagrant. But thanks for the info, it might be useful for future Googlers!

Comment: @FlorianMargaine, your answer helped and I wanted to share my experience in dealing with this issue.